# Youtube API v2 update on v3

Tags: php, youtube-data-api

https://gdata.youtube.com/feeds/api/user/userName/uploads?orderby=published&start-index=1&max-results=4

It works on v2, what should I change now, how can I fix it? I am reading the above link in PHP, and I have:

failed to open stream: HTTP request failed! HTTP/1.0 400 Bad Request
in /home/x/x.dev.local.x.pl/x/trunk/src/X/XBundle/Api/Youtube.php line 16

PHP code:

```
 `$feedURL = 'https://gdata.youtube.com/feeds/api/use//x/uploads?orderby=published&start-index=1&max-results=4';
```

And 16 line:

```
`$sxml = simplexml_load_file($feedURL);
```

Comment: Erm, may we see what code you are running? If this is a JavaScript library, have you checked whether you get any JS errors? What browser are you running? What problems are you experiencing? What is the significance of the link you have provided here?

Comment: This URL returns "Invalid request URI" and has a status code of 400, so that's not going to work. Have you read the docs for the new API version? Can we see your PHP code?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A lot of things changed in Api v3. You should really check the docs before migrating to v3 to make sure you don't mess things up.

Basically now you need to make 2 requests to retrieve a users uploads.
First get his profile:

```
GET https://www.googleapis.com/youtube/v3/channels?part=contentDetails&forUsername=google&key={YOUR_API_KEY}
```

From the result of this request take the uploads playlist id.

The next step is to retrive the videos from that specific playlist.

```
GET https://www.googleapis.com/youtube/v3/playlistItems?part=snippet%252CcontentDetails%252Cstatus&playlistId=UUK8sQmJBp8GCxrOtXWBpyEA&key={YOUR_API_KEY}
```

More details [here](https://developers.google.com/youtube/v3/guides/implementation/videos).
Also you can test the requests: [here](https://developers.google.com/apis-explorer/#p/youtube/v3/youtube.channels.list?part=contentDetails&forUsername=google&_h=13&) for the channel part and [here](https://developers.google.com/apis-explorer/#p/youtube/v3/youtube.playlistItems.list?part=snippet%252CcontentDetails%252Cstatus&playlistId=UUK8sQmJBp8GCxrOtXWBpyEA&_h=1&) for the playlist part.

Also the pagination is a bit different now. Now you must use a next page token(retreived from the request) rather than the numbers of items to take, skip.